# How remove dynamic substring from string in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to remove sub string from my string which is dynamic date time.

Example:

> Nov 19, 2019 05:41:08 AM EST

I need:

> Nov 19, 2019 05 AM EST this kind of string

I want to remove minutes and second from the string.

Answer (score 2):

You may try a regex string replacement:

```
String input = "Nov 19, 2019 05:41:08 AM EST";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\b(\\d{2}):\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\b", "$1");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
Nov 19, 2019 05 AM EST
```

A perhaps more robust approach would be to go back to the `Date`, `LocalDate/LocalDateTime` which generated the current output and instead format using the new mask you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to remove everything between the first `:` and the first blank space

```
String original = "Nov 19, 2019 05:41:08 AM EST"; 
String stripped = original.replaceAll(":.*? ", " ");
System.out.print(stripped); // prints Nov 19, 2019 05 AM EST
```

Comment: Thank you very much  Guy, your solution work for me


String original = "Nov 19, 2019 05:41:08 AM EST"; 
String stripped = original.replaceAll(":.*? ", " ");
System.out.print(stripped);

Comment: Or maybe `original.replaceAll(":.*?(?= )", "");`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not comfortable with RegEx, you can use the following solution:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String dateString="Nov 19, 2019 05:41:08 AM EST";
        String requiredString=dateString.replace(dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf(':'),dateString.indexOf(' ',dateString.indexOf(':'))),"");
        System.out.println(requiredString);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Nov 19, 2019 05 AM EST
```

There are many other ways as well e.g. using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)